# Roxygen2 says Error: file already exists .../RcppExports.cpp

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools, dplyr, roxygen2

I am practicing R package writing with Rcpp, devtools, and roxygen2. However, when I run document("mypkg") under the dev mode, I got the following error:

```
Updating mypkg documentation
Loading mypkg
Error: file already exists: 'mypkg/src/RcppExports.cpp'
```

My RcppExports.cpp file is very similar to the default Rcpp.package.skeleton.

What could possibly go wrong here?

I understand I probably should provide more relevant info, but I don't really have a clue. I would be happy to put more here if anyone has any suggestion.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The message `file already exists` comes from [this line in `Rcpp`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/ace139d6705c254d2ffd8f589cbe9a2e8ed823d6/src/attributes.cpp#L1392)

And the `isSafeToOverwrite` looks like this:

```
    // Check whether it's safe to overwrite this file (i.e. whether we
    // generated the file in the first place)
    bool isSafeToOverwrite() const {
        return existingCode_.empty() ||
               (existingCode_.find(generatorToken()) != std::string::npos);
    }
```

So my best guess is that something has happened to the generator token that `compileAttributes` puts on top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, "works for me" but I don't use devtools.

I would

- start with a fresh package just so see if / where it breaks
- make sure you are not being bitten by pre/post roxygen2 4.0 issues (there is converter script)
- maybe try with / without devtools -- I happily use build & reload in RStudio all the time on a current (non-public) package using roxygen2 along with Rcpp

Comment: the naive Rcpp skeleton package works. I will investigate further and update this post. Thx